# non-installed packages work when trying to import them in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I need some help with some weird things happening in jupyter.
It all started when I was trying to install tweepy, the package was installed successfully **but** it doesn't work when I try to import it in jupyter and it outputs this error: 
`ImportError: No module named 'tweepy'`
The package was installed via `pip`, first thing I checked was if the package was really installed in the environment or not..and it was. In short I tried the following:

- I uninstalled the package with `pip uninstall tweepy` and then installed it again with `pip install tweepy`.
- I then tried to install it with `conda install -c conda-forge tweepy`
- I then tried to install it from inside the notebook with `!conda install -y -c conda-forge tweepy`

Well..**nothing from the above did work, unfortunately**. and it was getting really frustrating!
I found this [post](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) which suggest this:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install package
```

It did work. but here is the weird thing: whatever package I import ,**even non-installed packages!**, the cell just work without any errors! and when I check the list of packages installed in a totally new environment that I created to test this, which does not have any packages installed, with `!conda list` I get empty list as expected **but** still any package I import still work!
So, can anyone help me understand what just happened?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use pip if you are using Anaconda.  Create a virtual environment by typing: conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda  where yourenvname is the name of your virtual environment and python=x.x is the version number of python you wish to use like python=3.8. Now after this activate you virtual environment. The type `conda install package`. And see if it works.

Comment: I did try installing with both pip and conda as said above, and also tried creating a new env. but still it didn't work! ..it worked after I tried the above suggested code from the post but it resulted in the strange behavior that I don't understand.(packages being imported successfully without being installed, regardless of the environment)

Comment: My point was using conda after using pip may cause problems. i would logout and log back in and try using only the comda command.